# Garbled response from Mailchimp Oauth2 token request ( CakePHP 2 )

Tags: cakephp, mailchimp, oauth-2.0

On the last call to retrieve a token I am doing the following:

```
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
  $q = array(
    'grant_type'=>'authorization_code',
    'client_id'=>Configure::read('Mailchimp.ClientId'),
    'client_secret'=>Configure::read('Mailchimp.ClientSecret'),
    'redirect_uri'=>urlencode(Router::url('/connected_apps/mailchimp', true)),
    'code'=>$_GET['code']
  );
  $res = $HttpSocket->post('http://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token', $q);
  echo($res->body());
  exit;
```

The response body is looking like this:

```
‹ÿÿ
```

Here is the outout from debugging the request.

```
'method' => 'POST',
'uri' => array(
    'host' => '*****',
    'port' => '*****',
    'scheme' => 'http',
    'user' => null,
    'pass' => null,
    'path' => '/oauth2/token',
    'query' => array(),
    'fragment' => null
),
'version' => '1.1',
'body' =>      'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=********&client_secret=********&redirect_uri=http%253A%252F%252Fdomain.com%252Fconnected_apps%252Fmailchimp&code=*********',
'line' => 'POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
',
'header' => 'Host: login.mailchimp.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 219
',
'raw' => 'POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.mailchimp.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 219

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=********&client_secret=********&redirect_uri=http%253A%252F%252Fdomain.com%252Fconnected_apps%252Fmailchimp&code=*********
',
'redirect' => false,
'cookies' => array(),
'proxy' => array(),
'auth' => array()
```

Comment: Did you try using https directly? Normally mailchimp redirects you to https on request..

Comment: Is the data that's being returned gzip encoded?